# Some icons display differently VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 application which is running under Windows 10 with admin rights.  The application is made up of various things but the main form (frmMain) has several buttons with icons on it.  Each of the icon files used is a 32x32 ico file and the majority display as they have always done.  I am finding though that about 40% are showing differently - mainly quite big and blocky.  I can't figure out any difference in the properties of the buttons they are associated or the files so why do some change and some don't?

Comment: A standard button control does not support icons, so you must be using some other kind of "button" or a third-party button that does support icons/pictures.  Can you elaborate on what kind of button, and perhaps add one or more screenshots to your original post?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your icons use a different color depth or if they are loaded at runtime they are stored in different ImageLists?